# Solving for $\omega_i$ given the recursive sequence $\omega_{i + 1} = \frac{7}{13}\omega_i + \frac{6}{13}\frac{v}{r}$ and $\omega_0 = 0$.

Tags: recursion

I am having trouble solving this recursive sequence
$$\omega_{i + 1} = \frac{7}{13}\omega_i + \frac{6}{13}\frac{v}{r}$$
given that $\omega_0 = 0$.

I tried using Engineer's Induction  but all it's leading to are messy fractions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, assuming $v$ and $r$ are constants, and defining $\alpha = \frac{v}{r}$ then this is an [arithmetico-geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence) and has the solution
$$\omega_n=\alpha\left(1-\left(\frac{7}{13}\right)^n\right)$$

**EDIT**: An explanation of my solution.
Let's consider a general AGP:
$$a_n=p \cdot a_{n-1} + q$$
With an initial value $a_0 = A$.
Then
$$a_0=A$$
$$a_1=pA+q$$
$$a_2=p(pA+q)+q$$
$$= p^2A + (p+1)q$$
$$a_3=p(p^2A+(p+1)q)+q$$
$$ = p^3A + (p^2+p+1)q$$
The pattern continues:
$$a_n = p^nA + q\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{p^k}$$
Using the formula for the partial sum of a geometric series,
$$a_n = p^nA + q\frac{1-p^{n}}{1-p}$$
In OP's case, $p=\frac{7}{13}$, $q=\frac{6\alpha}{13}$, and $\omega_0 = 0$ thus
$$\omega_n = \frac{6\alpha}{13}\frac{1-\left(\frac{7}{13}\right)^n}{1-\frac{7}{13}}=\alpha\left(1-\left(\frac{7}{13}\right)^{n}\right)$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how this resembles an arithmetico-geometric sequence. Can you explain more about how you got the answer? The answer itslef is correct.

Comment: @Ashmit Dutta An arithmetico-geometric sequence is any sequence of the form $a_{n+1}=p \cdot a_{n} + q$, which OP's example certainly is.

Answer (score 2):

*A simple way to see it.*

Consider
$$a_n=p \, a_{n-1} + q\qquad \qquad (p\ne 1)$$ Let $a_n=b_n+k$ and replace
$$b_n+k=p \, b_{n-1}+pk + q$$ Choose $k$ such that
$$k=pk+q \implies k=\frac q{1-p}\implies b_n=p \, b_{n-1}\implies b_n=C\, p^{n-1}$$ Back to $a$
$$a_n=C\, p^{n-1}+\frac q{1-p}\implies C=p \left(a_0-\frac{q}{1-p}\right)$$